# Is there a database or persistent storage, packaged in a Ruby gem?

Tags: ruby, database, persistence, rubygems

I have a simple Sinatra application that needs some persistence storage. If possible, that database should offer some access by id, and keyword search/find options.

Considering the nature of the to-be stored items, a document-based database seems the best fit.

Obviously I have considered MongoDB and CouchDB, but all have one problem: **they introduce dependencies on third party services**. I don't want that.

My users should install the Sinatra app as a gem, with its dependencies, run a single command and have everything running.

I am looking for solutions that come as a gem, run under the current user and are really simple. A prepackaged mongoDB would do, too, but I cannot find such a thing. Is SQLlite my only option?

Comment: I interpret your point to be that you some kind of embedded database, rather than a server, and he wants it packaged up in a gem (not requiring a second installer to get it in place, though you could live with something that's very likely to be in your deployment platform's base install).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want DBM (which gives you access by id) and [Ruby/odeum](http://rubygems.org/gems/ruby_odeum) which gives you keyword search.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider either a self-standing database like SQLite and Redis (no-SQL), or an ORM like DataMapper.

Comment: Where can I find more about Redis as self-standing database, instead of a system-wide server?